# Showing \r\n\ on Textarea using $_SESSION

Tags: php, session, textarea, line-breaks, nl2br

For example, if i submit this text and i put it in a $SESSION:

Line 1
 Line 2

When i try to show this text again in textarea, my text looks like this:

> Line 1\r\n\Line 2

My code is: (textarea)

```
<textarea class='input-model' name='corpo' id='corpo' rows="16" cols="112"  /><?php echo $corpo;?></textarea>
```

My PHP (that i send the textarea ):

```
$corpo = nl2br(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['corpo']));
```

My PHP (Put the session in a variable: $corpo)

```
$corpo = $_SESSION['upd-body'];
```

I tried to use replace or str_replace, and nothing work.

Somebody can help me?

Comment: Try without `mysql_real_escape_string()`. Also you should have `<br />` as line break

Comment: Should use `var_dump` and see what you are really dealing with, or at least view the page source.  Bet you can figure this out.  Rizier123 is correct by the way.